# 2005 Volvo S40 "KEY ERROR, TRY AGAIN"

Tags: starting, volvo, s40

Without no warning came out of Drs. and start getting "key error, try again" message on my S40 it wont start will not go into gear (to have towed) nothing and something drained the battery so I exchanged car battery and fob battery but still wont start and continues to show key error try again message. Also the new battery arched pretty badly upon installing along with all kinds of clicking noises. Can someone help me on this issue??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do you have a second key you can try? It sounds like the immobilizer is keeping you from starting the car. Also, there should be a brake pedal override on the shifter to allow you to put it into neutral to move the vehicle.

Comment: Did you fit the new car battery and the new fob battery at the same time? If so, did you re-code the fob to the car? As @Paulster2 suggested do you have a spare key?